# Starting a bounty out of the blue

Tags: feature-request

This is what the "start a bounty"-link looks like:
[image]
It is not blue and below the "add a comment"-link it looks very not-clickable.
Can we make the link cornflower-blue? Or maybe just the same color as "add a comment"?
It wouldn't break anything... probably.